# "def <=>" vs. "def method_missing"

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9.2

is there a way to use the spaceship method and the magic "method_missing" in one class? The below example gives me `undefined method '<'` whenever I try `foo1 < foo2` with a definiton like:

```
class Foo

  def initialize(params)
    @parent= params[:parent]
  end

  def <=>(o)
     ...
  end

  def method_missing(sym, *args, &block)
    @parent.send sym, *args, &block
  end
end
```

Any help appreciated :)

Comment: method_missing is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: so true - worked too long and didn't see the obvious ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**short answer:**

You're missing this line of code inside `Foo`:

```
include Comparable
```

**long answer:**

You don't get the `<`, `>`, `<=`, etc. methods just by redefining the spaceship operator.

You get those methods by including `Comparable`. Those methods **then** use the spaceship operator to provide a valid response.

It's more or less what happens with `Enumerable`:

you include the module, implement the `each` method, and then get all the other methods (`map`, `select`, etc) for "free".

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand what your question is. For the < and > methods to be created, put  `include Comparable` in your class definition and define the <=> instance method.